# How to resolve circular references for models in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am doing code first EF and creating domain models in separate projects because we want to logically group things into different projects since it is a large application. The problem I am running into is as soon as I have a model from one project related to a model from another project I now need the projects to reference each other for the navigation properties. This circular reference of course makes rebuilding the solutions impossible. Consider this example:

```
SecuritySolution
    SecurityProject1
        Domain Models
            Security.cs <-- has public Application Application {get;set;}

Now in a separate solution:
ApplicationSolution
    ApplicationProject1
        Domain Models
            Application.cs  <-- has public ICollection<Security> Securities {get;set;}
```

So now SecurityProject1 needs a reference to ApplicationProject1 and vice versa so if you try to do a clean build it fails. What are the best solutions to this? Can you use interfaces in the domain classes for code first EF?

Comment: If you want to separate your entities (I assume that's what you mean by domain models) then you really should do that on DB separation lines, even if you have a large DB.

Comment: Unfortunately EF was built on circular dependencies when designing DBModels code first. Something I've not been a fan of from the beginning but unfortunately it's the nature of how it works; and it uses those dependencies to set the right foreign keys etc in the DB.

Comment: Let both projects have their own `Application` and `Security` classes, maybe with a name prefix to tell them apart easier in intellisense.